# How to make narrow boldfont rule

Tags: fonts, bold

I find the Computer Modern font to be a little too wide, in my document, when making bold text. I found a solution though,

Instead of

```
\textbf{This font is bold.}
```

I can do

```
\scalebox{.8}[1.0]{\textbf{This text is bold and narrower.}}
```

For simplicity's and habit's sake when writing, I wish to set up a rule so that every time I type `\textbf{}` a substitution to `\scalebox{.8}[1.0]{\textbf{}}` is made.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

Scaling that font has lots of unwanted effects, preventing the white space from stretching, preventing linebreaking (not to mention distorting the font shape).

If you shrink by 80% the bold font is narrower than the standard font which is rather odd.

By default latex uses `bx` (bold extended) with computer modern, but there is also a `b` (bold non-extended) variant that you may prefer, as shown in the last example.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

This text is bold and narrower.

\scalebox{.8}[1.0]{\textbf{This text is bold and narrower.}}

\textbf{This text is bold and narrower.}

\renewcommand\bfdefault{b}% rather than bx

\textbf{This text is bold and narrower.}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I agree. 80% was a tad too much, plus I didn't know about the unwanted effects. The suggested bold non-extended is perfect!

Comment: @EirikL. `\scalebox` is like `\mbox` so it puts everything in an unbreakable box